# Pointing linked objects to a different library file in 2.8+

Tags: blend-files, linked-data

I've got individual files for each asst in my scene, and one file for the master scene with everything in it. In the master scene I'm linking in objects from the individual files by doing *File > Link...* and selecting a file and which object to import from it.

Questions:

- Selecting on object in my master scene, how can I see which file path it is being linked from?
- Having an object linked from e.g. `myAsset_v002.blend`, how can I make it link to `myAsset_v004.blend` once I've worked on and detailed that asset?

This is not a question about broken relative links

- I've found the *Edit Linked Library* add-on, which is pretty much the workflow I'm after. It even show's the path of the linked file. Only thing is it's editing the linked file in place without the ability to version up / link to a different file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linking to version numbered files is a bad practice and not very maintainable in the long run as you have already found out.

My advice is to never link to `myAsset_v002.blend` or `myAsset_v004.blend`, instead when you edit a library file always save "masters files" of all your libraries in addition to the revision ones named `myAsset.blend` (without version numbers) and link to that one instead. Otherwise you will spend more time managing libraries than getting actual work done.

Addressing the issue at hand you can switch the *Outliner* to *Blend File* mode from the dropdown, locate the desired file you which to remap, and from the <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> menu choose the *Relocate* option. Browse to the new substitution file.

[image]

You can't, as far as I can tell, quickly select all objects originating from the same blend file, but you can select all objects sharing the same datablock.

In the 3D view you can select all instances on a certain object-data by selecting one of them and from the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Select Linked* menu then picking the relevant entry depending on the library type (if it was linked directly as an object, or a collection instance).

[image]

You can take advantage of that and after linking in a new library from a different file, re-link all selected ones using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> *Make Links* menu, choosing once again the appropriate option depending on the library type.

[image]

Comment: Versioned files is exactly what I want, thanks for your opinion.